# How to connect two models

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, autoencoder

I have model A (autoencoder) which takes as input a batch of images A_in (original images), and outputs a batch of images A_out (reconstructed images). Then I have model B (binary classifier) which takes as input a batch of images B_in, which is a mixture of A_in and A_out.

I want B to distinguish between A_in and A_out, to see if A is doing a good job reconstructing images. B_out is a probability that a given image is A_in.

B trains in parallel with A to classify the two kinds of images. B_loss = (B_out - label). Labels are 0 or 1 (original or reconstructed). When we optimize B_loss we only update B parameters.

I want to train model A so that it optimizes a combined loss function: Combined_Loss = reconstruction error (A_out - A_in) - classification error (B_out - label), so that it tries to reconstruct the images and fool B at the same time. Here I want to only update A parameters (we don't want to help B here).

Now, my question is about constructing that mixture of A_in and A_out, and feeding it to B so that the graphs A and B are connected.

Right now it's like this:

```
A_out = autoencoder(A_in: orig_images)
B_out = classifier(B_in: numpy(mix(A_in, A_out))
```

How do I define it like this:

```
A_out = autoencoder(A_in: orig_images)
B_out = classifier(mix(A_out, A_in))
```

So that when I train A and B at the same time:

```
sess.run([autoencoder_train_op, classifier_train_op], feed_dict=
            {A_in: orig_images, B_in: classifier_images, labels: classifier_labels})
```

I wouldn't need B_in placeholder (the graphs would be connected)?

Here's my Numpy code that constructs classifier_images (mix(A_in, A_out)):

```
reconstr_images = sess.run(A_out, feed_dict={A_in: orig_images})

half_and_half_images = np.concatenate((reconstr_images[:batch_size/2], orig_images[batch_size/2:]))

half_and_half_labels = np.zeros(labels.shape)
half_and_half_labels[batch_size/2:] = 1

random_indices = np.random.permutation(batch_size)

classifier_images = half_and_half_images[random_indices]
classifier_labels = half_and_half_labels[random_indices]
```

How do I convert it into TensorFlow node?

Comment: Is there any specific issue you are facing converting this code to tf? It seems like pretty straightforward code that should be doable using `tf.concat`, `tf.zeros`, `tf.random_shuffle`, etc. Also, I am not sure why you need to shuffle at all. Presumably the different images being fed at the same time is just for batching and are processed independently. If so, you should not need to shuffle, unless you batch size is large and you want to shuffle for better optimization trajectories.

Comment: Good point about shuffling - it's not needed. However that does not change the main question: how to convert classifier(B_in: numpy(mix(A_in, A_out)) to classifier(mix(A_out, A_in)) so that the two graphs are connected?

Comment: I see. I somehow missed that question. I will try answering it with an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can connect your models directly. In other words, you don't use placeholder for B's inputs, but use your mixture of A_in and A_out. If you just want to run B, you can still feed your inputs into the tensors that are coming from A. Feeding only placeholders is common, but TensorFlow supports feeding a value into any tensor. If it makes it easier to think about, you can pass the A's outputs through `tf.identity` so that you have something like a placeholder.

Another approach is what is usually done in GANs (where the generator output is fed into discriminator). You can create two "towers" of operations that share the variables. One tower will be just B and you can feed your inputs into B's placeholders to run just B. Another tower can be B on top of A, which you can use to run/train A and B together. The Bs in these two towers will have the same structure and share variables, but have separate ops. This approach is likely the cleanest and most flexible.

Comment: "but use your mixture of A_in and A_out"

That's exactly what I'd like to know: how to do that? 
I'm wondering if I can do it like this: 

`A_out = autoencoder(A_in: orig_images)
mixed = tf.concat(A_out, A_in)
B_out = classifier(mixed)`

Comment: I might be missing something, but why do you think it can be a problem? As long as it is logically correct and shapes match.... What problems are you expecting?

Comment: I don't know what arguments `classifier` expects, so it is hard to tell anything. It it expects concrete values that are used in `feed_dict`, it won't "connect" the models. If it expects tensors and uses them as inputs to its ops, it will "connect" the models.

Comment: The classifier expects a batch of images. To connect it to the autoencoder, I have to take the tensor which is a batch of images (output of the autoencoder), and use it as input to the classifier. As described in my question, I cannot do that, because the input has to be a mixture of the AE output images, and original images. So in my comment above I proposed creating an intermediate tf node tf.concat(A_out, A_in), and feed that to the classifier instead. I haven't tried it yet, so I don't know if it will work.